# Authenticate on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am stuck on a specific piece and I can't seem to figure it out, so what I'm attempting to do is that I have a button and when it's clicked, it will open the link in the window and the users will authenticate and then it will redirect back to the page with a code from Instagram.

What I'm attempting to do:

1. When someone clicks on the `#insta-auth` button, it will open the `getAuthentication` function link in the same tab.
2. So let's say that `window.location.origin` is `https://test.com/`, the Instagram URL will return it as `https://test.com/?code=debsfbdfb`.

For some reason, I attempted `onclick=""` and `$().onClick` and nothing has worked so far, all help would be appreciated!

**The snippet shows the button**.

```js
// Setup out Instagram object
var FHInstagram = window.FHInstagram || {};
FHInstagram.name = "";
FHInstagram.version = "2.0.0";

(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    
    // Define our Instagram object
    const Instagram = {
        APP_ID: '32222516',
        API_URL: 'https://graph.instagram.com/',
        API_OAUTH: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize',
        API_OAUTH_TOKEN_URL: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
        API_FIELDS: 'caption,media_url,media_type,permalink,timestamp,username',

    // Authenticate Instagram
    getAuthentication: function () {
        return "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + this.APP_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + window.location.origin + "&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code";
    },
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="insta-authenticate">Authenticate Instagram</button>
```

Comment: I don't know how Instagram works, but generally you want to encode something like `origin` when putting it in a URL, so `+ encodeURIComponent(window.location.origin) +`... Also, be careful with what information you publish in questions...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, how can I trigger `getAuthentication` return link when the button is clicked?

Comment: Again, I have no idea how Instagram works, so I can't answer your question. There are plenty of questions about how to call functions when a button is clicked on the site though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#insta-authenticate').on('click', function() {
 -- do your instagram stuff here, getAuthentication(); 
}
```

Comment: If I put that outside the `(function ($, ...)(jQuery, window, document)`, I keep getting a `getAuthentication() is not a function` error.

Comment: Because getAuthenticate is no longer in the correct scope, move
'getAuthentication()' and your const Instagram object
  outside 
'(function (function ($, ...)(jQuery, window, document)'